# xlPasteValues not giving a syntax error (Trying to not copy and paste the table connection)

Tags: vba

I've got the following code

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(range_to_copy).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(range_to_paste)
```

This code works perfectly, but when I paste the data, it also duplicates the connection to the database that I originally set up.

[image]

So I've been trying to avoid that by using "xlPasteValues" but when I try this it gives me a syntax error.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(range_to_copy).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(range_to_paste).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Not sure of what I am doing wrong, could somebody help me with this? Thank you

Comment: xlPasteValues is nothing but a constant value equal to -4163. Values starting with xl is almost always something like that. Press F2 in VBE and search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in 2 separate lines of code. Here is an example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```